# Insert a page break in a generated HTML .doc

Tags: html, asp.net, ms-word

I am currently generating a .doc file as **html** using asp.NET.

I wish to insert a page break to the page but don't know how.

I've tried using the css style='page-break-before:always' but it does nothing.

This is the code assigned to a button click event:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset ="";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType ="application/msword";

    string strFileName = "GenerateDocument"+ ".doc";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=" + strFileName);

    StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();

    strHTMLContent.Append("<p align='Center'>Content Before Page Break</p>".ToString());

    strHTMLContent.Append("<br><br>".ToString());
    strHTMLContent.Append("<p class='pageBreak' style='mso-special-character:line-break;'>meh</p>".ToString());

    strHTMLContent.Append("<br><br>".ToString()); 
    strHTMLContent.Append("<p align='Center'>Content After Page Break</p>".ToString());

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Comment: You're creating a MS Word document with HTML?

Comment: Claiming that the document is MS Word doesn't make it MS Word. It just makes whatever application the user has configured to handle Word documents try to process an HTML document. If you want to serve up an MS Word document, then generate a real one. Don't send HTML wrapped in a bundle of lies.

Comment: You might be better off looking at the `docx` specification - You could generate it in a similar way and be outputting a supported format rather than hoping word/whatever program handles `doc` files can pick up the pieces

Comment: @David Dorward I realise what you're saying here but so far this solution works, unless of course I can't figure how to insert a page break. How would you suggest doing it the 'real' way?

Comment: Find a library for generating Word documents (or read the specification and write a basic one that covers your needs). Then use that. (and FSVOW — have you tested it with every software package that people use to read Word documents?)

Comment: @David Dorward, thanks for your input. I will research alternative methods to my problem.

Comment: @baked: did you try to print (or even "print preview") the document? I've done some testing recently, and `page-break-before` _does_ work; but MS Word defaults to Web design view when opening an HTML document, and Web design view (just like browsers) doesn't render page-breaks. Even switching to "Print design view" should allow you to see that your page-break is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Gios.Word .NET library instead. Much simpler to create RTF compatible word files with tables and page breaks etc.

I tried to create XML based Doc files first and found that Gios is better:

Here is an article about it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/gioswordnetlibrary.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=11252

Answer (score 17):

Word has its own special classes. mso-special-character:page-break; does work in this situation, as mentioned by Pekka, however what is missing is this should be on a <br> tag. So the following code will work:

```
<br clear=all style='mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always'>
```

It's not particularly nice solution, but in my case I had no choice (I didn't write the original code, and it was a much bigger job to change it).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what Office's notation for that is, but I would create a document with a page break in Word, save it as HTML, and look what it uses.

Guessing from the code block you show, it *could* be

```
mso-special-character:page-break;
```

Comment: I have already tried this with no result. I'm guessing MS strips it when it opens a html file?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes across this and the accepted answer isn't possible or CodePB's answer doesn't work, use the following. I simply took 'line-break' out and replaced it with 'page-break' and this seemed to work out of the box.

```
<br clear=all style='mso-special-character:page-break;page-break-before:always'>
```

Answer (score -3):

**Don't generate MS Word files with HTML**

You wouldn't want to build a house with the plans for a boat would you?

If you're wanting to do this programmatically I suggest you either take a look at the docx format or even the rich text format specification and move from there.  But in all likelyhood you're going down the wrong path and theres already libraries out there that you can use.

I suggest you [start here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/creatingandopeningmicrosoftdocumentfrom.netusingcsharp11262005050939am/creatingandopeningmicrosoftdocumentfrom.netusingcsharp.aspx)

Comment: No, OF COURSE that using OLE objects or going to the docx specification is a step BACK, not forward. Yeah, those specifications not only look tempting, but moreover I've known them and have also fell in love with them in the past. BUT they imply to BEGIN AGAIN to format a document. Learning to transform from html to doc SUPERSEDES this, in the sense that one effort (a good effort, of course) would work both for a web page and for an editable word document, or even a printed document. ONE effort, ONE change affecting everything each time, not having to begin again each time.